# Mix and Max not working properly in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, max, min

I have this code in VB.NET

```
   Dim numeros(9) As Integer
   For Each numerito In numeros
       numerito = Val(InputBox("Ingrese un numero"))
   Next

   txtResultadoMayor.Text = Val(numeros.Max())
   txtResultadoMenor.Text = Val(numeros.Min())
```

It should be really straightforward and give me the max and min values but both Min() and Max() are returning 0. Why is this so?

Comment: Because you don't know how arrays work.  Use a `For` loop and set each element by index. Your `For Each` loop never changes the array so the only values in it are zero so of course that's what `Min` and `Max` return. Basic debugging would have told you that.

Comment: You are not adding the elements that you read from the user to the array numeros

Comment: Why is VB not filling the array with a for each? is there a way to change the behavior of the For each somehow? I found a for and while loop dirty for this simple task

Comment: Because you don't know how arrays work. As @jmcilhinney already pointed out. You really need to study the basics first.

Comment: "I found a for and while loop dirty for this simple task". Use the right loop for the task at hand. A `While` loop would be completely inappropriate. A `For Each` loop is also completely inappropriate.  A `For Each` loop is for USING each item in a list. Is that what you're doing here? No, it isn't. A `For` loop is appropriate when accessing each item in an `ILIst` by index.  That's exactly what you need to do here so a `For` loop is the perfect option.  It does exactly what you need to do.

Comment: "Dirty" is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to add the numbers to the array

```
   Dim numeros(9) As Integer
   For index As Integer = 0 To numeros.Count - 1
       numeros(index) = Val(InputBox("Ingrese un numero"))
   Next

   txtResultadoMayor.Text = Val(numeros.Max())
   txtResultadoMenor.Text = Val(numeros.Min())
```

Comment: I want the for each to create a reference to the memory address, not just make a temporary copy. For instance, if I iterate through a collection of controls, I can access the references themselves and change the background color to name something. Why I cant do it here?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios The numeros array have values or not? Its not cleat what you want to achive

Comment: Because it's not the same thing. I've already told you what's going on. In the example you describe, you are USING each item in the array.  You're not actually SETTING any elements. If, in that case, rather than change the `BackColor` of each control you wanted to actually put new controls into the array then you would have exactly the same issue as you are having now. Read the words: you CAN NOT set the elements of an array or any other list using a `For Each` loop that enumerates that list. Use a `For` loop as you have already been told is the solution.

Comment: Think about what you're actually doing. In the example you mention, for each control already in the array, you take the next element and assign it to a variable, then you change the `BackColor` of the object assigned to that variable. No problem. You only ever pull items out of the array. You never even try to push items into the array. Now consider the scenario you asked about in the first place. You initialise an `Integer` array, so you have an array containing ten `Integers` and each element is zero by default. TBC

Comment: Then, for each `Integer` in the array, you assign that `Integer` (which is zero) to a variable, then you prompt the user for a value and you assign it to that same variable, then you move on. Where in that did you ever put the value the user provided into the array?  You didn't, and that's the problem. This wouldn't even work with reference types but `Integer` is a value type so how could your loop control variable magically refer to the array element? Obviously you WANT the loop control variable to be a pointer to the array element but that is NOT how it works. USE A `For` LOOP!

Comment: @jmcilhinney [Do you need a snickers bar?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UO2A2p-19A)

Comment: I appreciate your inputs @jmcilhinney and I understand what you are saying. I was intrigued to know if there was a way to make the assignment directly to wherever the internal for each variable was pointing instead to some copy. Chill dude. :)

Comment: @LarsTech, more [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXL8QPWLbBo) I think.

Comment: @LarsTech hahaha

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, when you're told what the solution is and you say "but I don't want to do it that way, I want to do it the way I'm doing it that doesn't work" you should not be surprised if someone gets annoyed. You should have learned how `For Each` loops work before asking the question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney one last question, please dont kill me, is this a common thing in programming languages that I simply miss, or is something only specific to VB.Net?

Comment: Not all languages have a construct equivalent to a `For Each` loop in the first place. For instance, C/C++ would allow you to create a pointer to the array elements but you'd still be using a `for` loop and incrementing the pointer. I think that's correct but I haven't used C/C++ for a long time. In VB.NET and C#, the loop control variable in a `For Each` loop is basically like any other variable.  It behaves in the same way as any other variable to which you assigned an array element or list item.  It contains the value/object from the element/item but it is not the element/item itself.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. It will help you avoid runtime errors. Also dump the old vb6 Val() method and use one of the following. `.Parse`, `.TryParse`, `CType(value, Type)`, `CInt()` etc., `Convert.ToInt32 `(slow) Preferably `.TryParse` when dealing with user input.